# TypeError: Object of type 'Tag' is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I am trying to create a `JSON` object and send it to the `Firebase Database` using `python`, but when I do this I get:

`TypeError: Object of type 'Tag' is not JSON serializable`

Here is my code:

```
data = {'address': address,
    'name': name
   }

print(type(data))
sent = json.dumps(data)
result = firebase.post("/tHouse/houseTest", sent)
```

The is something wrong with `json.dumps(data)` since the error is pointed out here. Running `print(type(data))` returns though `<class 'dict'>`.

Also the `name` and `address` are set beforehand

Comment: What are the types of `address` and `name`?

Comment: with `address = "address"`, `name = "name"` your code works fine until `json.dumps(data)` Add full traceback so that someone can help

Comment: `name` is `String`, but `address` seems to be `'bs4.element.Tag'` ... can I just do `str(address)` to fix this ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Being a `bs4.element.Tag`, `address` can not be serialised to JSON.

How you handle this depends on what part of the tag you want to store in your db. If you just call `str()` on the `Tag` the output will include the XML/HTML markup. If you want the text contained within the tag, access the `.text` attribute e.g.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup('<address>1 Some Street Somewhere ABC 12345</address>')
address = soup.address

>>> type(address)
<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>
>>> str(address)
'<address>1 Some Street Somewhere ABC 12345</address>'
>>> address.text
u'1 Some Street Somewhere ABC 12345'
```

So this might be what you need to do:

```
data = {'address': address.text, 'name': 'Some One'}
>>> json.dumps(data)
'{"name": "Some One", "address": "1 Some Street Somewhere ABC 12345"}'
```

Answer (score -2):

You can convert data by looping through found items and finding what attribute you are looking for.

For example, if we have a list (with TAG's) of images. We can loop through it and create a list where we would append-only strings with URL's.

```
final = []
for i in images:
    image = i.attrs['src']
    final.append(image)
```